# python TarFile.extractall command deletes the files in the target directory

Tags: python, python-2.7

this is a simple piece of code in our production env. Python version 2.7

```
tar = tarfile.open(fileobj=pipe, mode='r|gz')
tar.extractall(d)
```

The finally blocks closes the tar file also.

```
   finally:
        if tar:
            tar.close()
```

However, on windows it is observed that some files in the target directory are deleted after the extractall().
Is this possible ? has anyone seen such issue before ?

Windows is windows 2016

Comment: The title says it overwrites them, the text says it deletes them. Which is it?

Comment: Oops...Title should say it "deletes" .  Thanks for pointing this out.  not sure how can I edit the title. ?

Comment: Click on the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66126828/edit) link right below the question.

Comment: Is there any pattern to which files are deleted? Does it delete all files that aren't in the tarfile? If so, it sounds like it's recreating the directory completely from the tarfile, rather than merging into the directory.

Comment: but the python API to untar \ extract is not supposed to delete the existing files. It is supposed to merge. I think some windows process\settings is having an overhang here ... I am wondering what could it be ?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience tarfile.extractall() overwrites files and directories. If you edit some extracted files and than run again extractall(), you will obtain the "original" files.